# Why using pymysql to operate the MySQL with Class does not work, but contextlib works well?

Tags: python, pymysql

I use pymysql (python3.5)to operate the MySQL(ver>5.5), and I want to use it simply, so I write a Class:

```py
class Mysql(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self.conn = connect(host=HOST, port=PORT, user=USER, passwd=PASSWORD, db=DB, charset=CHARSET)
       """DictCursor：A cursor which returns results as a dictionary"""
       self.cursor = self.conn.cursor(cursor=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

   def __enter__(self):
       return self.cursor

   def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
       self.cursor.close()
       self.conn.close()
```

Then, I wrote this:

```py
def do_add(_name, _age):
    with Mysql() as cursor:
        param = (_name, _age)
        sql = """insert into mydb(name, age) values (%s, %s)"""
        cursor.execute(sql, param)
```

That does not work, I can not insert data into MySQL.
But, when I use the context Manager, it works very well:

```py
@contextlib.contextmanager
def mysql():
    conn = connect(host=HOST, port=PORT, user=USER, passwd=PASSWORD, db=DB, charset=CHARSET)
    cursor = conn.cursor(cursor=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    try:
        yield cursor
        conn.commit()
    except:
        conn.rollback()
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
```

I want to know why I can not use Class?

Comment: Because you need to commit after inserting.

Comment: Probably in `__exit__` you need a first line saying `self.conn.commit()`...

Comment: silly me, ╯︿╰, I forget commit,  thank you all !